# Overfull \vbox for my title with a custom class

Tags: titles

I am currently trying to send a paper to FPSAC. So far so good, but I have the following warning:

```
Overfull \vbox (3.26552pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
```

I know where it occurs: it's the title. The class is the following (which I CANNOT change by requirement of the submission):

```
% Copyright 2018 Nicholas Beaton

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{FPSAC2021}[2020/09/02 FPSAC 2021 Proceedings class]

\newif \if@submission
\global \@submissionfalse
\DeclareOption{submission}{
  \global \@submissiontrue
}

\newif \if@revision
\global \@revisionfalse
\DeclareOption{revision}{
  \global \@submissiontrue
  \global \@revisiontrue
}

\newif \if@finalversion
\DeclareOption{finalversion}{
  \global \@submissiontrue
  \global \@revisiontrue
  \global \@finalversiontrue
}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1in,includehead]{geometry}
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=RoyalBlue,linkcolor=Red,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{lastpage}

\RequirePackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{caption}

\RequirePackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}

\RequirePackage[capitalize,nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}

% \setlength \textheight{56pc}
% \setlength \textwidth{35pc}
% \setlength \headsep{30\p@}
% \setlength \footskip{10\p@}
% \setlength \oddsidemargin{10\p@}
% \setlength \evensidemargin{21\p@}
% \setlength \textfloatsep{13\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 4\p@}
% \setlength \dbltextfloatsep{13\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 4\p@}
% \setlength \parskip{\z@ \@plus 1\p@}
% \setlength \parindent{10\p@}
% \setlength \topsep{4\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 1\p@}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\def\@title{\relax}
\def\@titlehead{\relax}
% pulling the title information from source
\def \title{\@ifnextchar[{\@gettitletwo}{\@gettitleone}}
\def \@gettitleone#1{\@gettitletwo[#1]{#1}}
\def \@gettitletwo[#1]#2{{
  \gdef \@title{#2}
  \def \\{\unskip \space \ignorespaces}
  \gdef \@titlehead{#1}
}}

\newif \if@marksrequired
\newcommand \addressmark[1]{%
  \if@marksrequired%
    $^{#1}$%
  \fi%
}
\global \@marksrequiredfalse
\gdef \and{\unskip \space \@authorand \space \ignorespaces}
\gdef \@authorand{and}


\def\@author{\relax}
\def\@authorhead{\relax}
% pulling the author information from source
\def \author{\@ifnextchar[{\@getauthortwo}{\@getauthorone}}
\def \@getauthorone#1{\@getauthortwo[#1]{#1}}
\def \@getauthortwo[#1]#2{{
  \gdef \@author{#2}
  \def \\{\unskip \space \ignorespaces}
  \gdef \@authorhead{#1}
}}

\def\@address{\relax}
% pulling address information from source
\def \address{\@getaddress}
\def \@getaddress#1{{
  \gdef \@address{#1}
}}

\newif \if@keywordsgiven
\@keywordsgivenfalse
\def\@keywords{\relax}
% pulling keywords information from source
\def \keywords{\@getkeywords}
\def \@getkeywords#1{{
  \global \@keywordsgiventrue
  \gdef \@keywords{#1}
}}

\def \@received{\relax}
\newcommand \received[1]{
  \gdef\@received{Received #1}
}
\def \@revised{\relax}
\newcommand \revised[1]{
  \gdef\@revised{revised #1}
}
\def \@accepted{\relax}
\newcommand \accepted[1]{
  \def\@accepted{accepted #1}
}

\newif \if@abstractgiven
\@abstractgivenfalse
\def \@abstract{\relax}
\long\def \abstract#1{
  \global \@abstractgiventrue
  \long\gdef \@abstract{#1}
}

\newif \if@resumegiven
\@resumegivenfalse
\def \@resume{\relax}
\long\def \resume#1{
  \global \@resumegiventrue
  \long\gdef \@resume{#1}
}

\def \@resumetitle{\relax}
\long\gdef \@resumetitle{Abstract}
\long\def \resumetitle#1{
  \long\gdef \@resumetitle{#1}
}

\def \@articlenumber{YY}
\def \articlenumber#1{\gdef \@articlenumber{#1}}

%%%%%%% BIBLATEX STUFF %%%%%%%

%\RequirePackage[maxbibnames=99,backend=bibtex,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
%\renewbibmacro{in:}{. In:}
%\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1}}
%\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\small}
%\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
%\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\textsc{url}: \href{#1}{#1}}
%\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{\textsc{doi}: \href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{#1}}
%\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:arxiv}{arXiv:\href{https://arxiv.org/abs/#1}{#1}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\let \pagenumber=\@gobble

\AtBeginDocument{\gdef \@thefirstpage{\thepage}}

\long \gdef \@firsthead{\parbox{\textwidth}{\footnotesize \textit{S\'eminaire Lotharingien de Combinatoire} XX (2021) \hfill \textit{Proceedings of the 33$^\text{rd}$ Conference on Formal Power} \newline Article \#\@articlenumber, \pageref*{LastPage} pp. \hfill \textit{Series and Algebraic Combinatorics (Ramat Gan)}}}


\def \ps@first{
  \def \@evenhead{\normalfont \@firsthead \hss}
  \def \@oddhead{\normalfont \@firsthead \hss }
}

\global \@twosidetrue

\def \ps@journal{
  \let \@mkboth \@gobbletwo
  \def \@evenhead{
    \def \thanks####1{\relax}%
    \small \thepage \hfill \textit{\@authorhead}
  }
  \def \@oddfoot{}
  \def \@oddhead{
    \small \textit{\@titlehead} \hfill \thepage
  }
  \def \@evenfoot{}
}

\renewcommand \maketitle{
  \thispagestyle{first}
  \renewcommand \thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
  \@maketitle
  \@thanks
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{\arabic{footnote}}

  \@makeabstract
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}
}

\newcommand \printkeywords{
  \small \noindent \textbf{Keywords:} \@keywords \par
}

\newenvironment{titlesp}{
  \list{}{
    \leftmargin 0pt
  }\item[]
}{\endlist}

\newenvironment{abstractsp}{
  \list{}{
    \leftmargin 25pt
    \rightmargin 25pt
  }\item[]
}{\endlist}

\def \@maketitle{
  \begin{titlesp}
    \begingroup
    \hypersetup{hidelinks}
    \@marksrequiredtrue
    \null % this is a very annoying way to add space before the title
    \vspace{-19\p@}
    {\centering \hyphenpenalty=\@M \LARGE \@title \par}
    \vspace{12\p@}
    {\centering \large \@author \par}
    \vspace{6\p@}
%    {\centering \small \itshape \@address \par}
    \begin{abstractsp} {\small \itshape \@address \par} \end{abstractsp}
%    {\small \itshape \@address \par}
%    \vspace{6\p@}
%    \if@submission{\small{\@received}}\fi%
%    \if@revision{\small{; \@revised}}\fi%
%    \if@finalversion{\small{; \@accepted}}\fi%
%    \if@submission{\small{.}\vspace{0\p@}}\fi
%    % \hrule \@height 1\p@
    \endgroup
  \end{titlesp}
}

\def \@makeabstract{
  \begin{abstractsp}
    \vspace{-10\p@}
    \bgroup
    \small
    \if@abstractgiven{\noindent{\textbf{Abstract.} \@abstract \par}}\fi
    \if@resumegiven{\noindent{\textbf{\@resumetitle.} \@resume \par}}\fi
    \if@keywordsgiven{\printkeywords}\fi
    \egroup
  \end{abstractsp}
  % \vspace{8\p@}
  % \hrule \@height 1\p@
}

\pagestyle{journal}

\newlength{\capsize}
%\setlength{\capsize}{\textwidth-50pt}

\long \def \@makecaption#1#2{%
%\newlength{\capsize}
\setlength{\capsize}{\textwidth-50pt}
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#2}
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa = 0pt
    \def \thistype{#1}
  \else
    \def \thistype{#1:}
  \fi
  \vskip \abovecaptionskip%
  \small%
  \sbox \@tempboxa{\textbf{\thistype} #2}%
  \ifdim \wd \@tempboxa > \capsize%
    \begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{\capsize}
      \textbf{\thistype} #2 \par
    \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
  \else%
    \global \@minipagefalse%
    \hb@xt@ \hsize{\hfil \box\@tempboxa \hfil}%
  \fi%
  \vskip \belowcaptionskip%
}

\newcommand \acknowledgments{\section*{Acknowledgments}}
\newcommand \acknowledgements{\section*{Acknowledgements}}
\newcommand \noabstract{\printkeywords}


\endinput
% end of file
```

Now my code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[submission]{FPSAC2021}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{ytableau}
\usepackage{extpfeil}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\title{A new order on integer partitions}

\author{Étienne Tétreault \thanks{\href{mailto: tetreault.etienne@courrier.uqam.ca}{tetreault.etienne@courrier.uqam.ca}.}\addressmark{1}}

\address{\addressmark{1}Département de mathématiques, Université du Québec à Montréal}

\received{\today}

\abstract{Considering Schur positivity of differences of plethysms of homogeneous symmetric functions, we introduce a new relation on integer partitions. This relation is conjectured to be a partial order, with its restriction to one part partitions equivalent to the classical Foulkes conjecture. We establish some of the properties of this relation via the construction of explicit inclusion of modules whose characters correspond to the plethysms considered. We also prove some stability properties for the number of irreducible occurring in these modules as $n$ grows.}

\keywords{Representation theory, plethysm, symmetric group}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Does someone know what I can do to get rid of this without changing the class? I don't know enough about custom classes to understand exactly what happens...

Comment: Does it matter? It's a warning which means that your file will compile fine. But this particular title is a little over 3 points too high for what Latex deems a good fit for the box allocated to it. Is FPSAC going to complain about this?

Comment: Well the display of my title, adressmark, abstract and keyword is really not the not one require, there is no space between them, so visually it is not the same and not really appealing... I guess I could modify the class a little as they only require the PDF, but there should be a way not to...

Comment: I have a sample which gives the same bad box, but this time the display is good, so I don't know what is going on

Comment: It is very tricky with these very specific templates when you don't really know what happens when you put text into it. I can't really tell either what could be going on but if something was annoying me size-wise and the output is what matters I would probably try something like scalebox to bring the misbehaving element into line.

Comment: You can also play with the optional argument [short title] of \title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the header, not from  your title, which is fine.
Without altering the class, you can expand the head height in your preamble and the warning will disappear.
(It is not necessary to load the xcolor package. It is already included in the class).

The class is tailor-made for the event. Perhaps you should send a comment to the organizers as the same problem will affect other equally observant participants.

```
\documentclass[submission]{FPSAC2021}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}

%\usepackage{ytableau} % not needed for this  MWE
%\usepackage{extpfeil} % not needed for this  MWE
%\usepackage{bm} % not needed for this  MWE

%\usepackage{xcolor}  % not needed, already include in the class

\usepackage{kantlipsum} %dummy text

\setlength{\headheight}{16pt} % <<<< added

\title{A new order on integer partitions}

\author{Étienne Tétreault \thanks{\href{mailto: tetreault.etienne@courrier.uqam.ca}{tetreault.etienne@courrier.uqam.ca}.}\addressmark{1}}

\address{\addressmark{1}Département de mathématiques, Université du Québec à Montréal}

\received{\today}

\abstract{Considering Schur positivity of differences of plethysms of homogeneous symmetric functions, we introduce a new relation on integer partitions. This relation is conjectured to be a partial order, with its restriction to one part partitions equivalent to the classical Foulkes conjecture. We establish some of the properties of this relation via the construction of explicit inclusion of modules whose characters correspond to the plethysms considered. We also prove some stability properties for the number of irreducible occurring in these modules as $n$ grows.}

\keywords{Representation theory, plethysm, symmetric group}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\kant[1-7]
\end{document}
```

This is the output using

```
\setlength{\headheight}{16pt}
```

[image: Set]

and this without it (as in your original file) and producing

```
Overfull \vbox (3.26552pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
```

As you can see the pagination is exactly the same.

[image: noset]